# How is it possible to increase value for dynamic property in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to icrease a dynamic value on my database which depends on user's mark, lets say there is a "vote" object with 3 parameters:

```
//data structure : 
_id : someObjectId,
gameId : someObjectId,
votes : { 
a: 0,
b: 0,
c: 0
}


userVote = { vote: 'b', gameId: '5cf3c5cc1c9d44000053defb' }

function addVote(userVote) {
    userVote.gameId = new ObjectId(userVote.gameId)
    return mongoService.connect()
        .then(db => {
            const collection = db.collection('totalVotes');
            return collection.updateOne(
                { gameId: userVote.gameId },
                { $inc: { "votes[userVote[vote]":1 } }
             )
        })
}
```

So, of course, the "inc" line isn't working that way, how is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has no way of knowing what `votes[userVote[vote]` even means (syntax error aside). It has no access to your client-side JavaScript. If you want to set this dynamically, change your `$inc` line to the following:

```
{ $inc: { ["votes." + userVote.vote] : 1 } }
```

If the bracket notation above is not supported, you can try something like the following instead:

```
let incVote = {};
incVote["votes." + userVote.vote] = 1;
return collection.updateOne(
    { gameId: userVote.gameId },
    { $inc: incVote }
);
```

Comment: If this answer resolved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.